# Zabbix 3.4 returned problem lib php-mbstring and php-bcmath on Oracle Linux

Tags: oracle-linux, zabbix

I have OS

```
NAME="Oracle Linux Server"
VERSION="7.4"
ID="ol"
VERSION_ID="7.4"
PRETTY_NAME="Oracle Linux Server 7.4"
ANSI_COLOR="0;31"
CPE_NAME="cpe:/o:oracle:linux:7:4:server"
HOME_URL="https://linux.oracle.com/"
BUG_REPORT_URL="https://bugzilla.oracle.com/"

ORACLE_BUGZILLA_PRODUCT="Oracle Linux 7"
ORACLE_BUGZILLA_PRODUCT_VERSION=7.4
ORACLE_SUPPORT_PRODUCT="Oracle Linux"
ORACLE_SUPPORT_PRODUCT_VERSION=7.4
```

Tried to install zabbix 3.4

```
 rpm -Uvh http://repo.zabbix.com/zabbix/3.4/rhel/7/x86_64/zabbix-release-3.4-1.el7.centos.noarch.rpm
and

yum install zabbix-server-mysql zabbix-web-mysql
```

and returned error

```
Error: Package: zabbix-web-3.4.1-1.el7.noarch (zabbix)
           Requires: php-mbstring
Error: Package: zabbix-web-3.4.1-1.el7.noarch (zabbix)
           Requires: php-bcmath
```

What repository you can advise to connect to enable correct versions of libraries?

tried variant from Franciscon Santos

```
[root@zabbixapp01 zabbix]# yum install -y php-bcmath.x86_64
Loaded plugins: replace, ulninfo
No package php-bcmath.x86_64 available.
Error: Nothing to do
[root@zabbixapp01 zabbix]# yum install -y php-bcmath.x86_64
Loaded plugins: replace, ulninfo
No package php-bcmath.x86_64 available.
Error: Nothing to do
[root@zabbixapp01 zabbix]# yum install -y php-mbstring.x86_64
Loaded plugins: replace, ulninfo
No package php-mbstring.x86_64 available.
Error: Nothing to do
```

repo list:

```
Loaded plugins: replace, ulninfo
repo id                                     repo name                                                                                        status
*epel/x86_64                                Extra Packages for Enterprise Linux 7 - x86_64                                                         11,948
ol7_UEKR4/x86_64                            Latest Unbreakable Enterprise Kernel Release 4 for Oracle Linux 7Server (x86_64)                       335+93
ol7_latest/x86_64                           Oracle Linux 7Server Latest (x86_64)                                                             17,653+5,136
zabbix/x86_64                               Zabbix Official Repository - x86_64                                                                        28
zabbix-non-supported/x86_64                 Zabbix Official Repository non-supported - x86_64
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Install the follow packets:

php-mbstring.x86_64

php-bcmath.x86_64

**Commands:**

yum install -y php-bcmath.x86_64

yum install -y php-mbstring.x86_64

Comment: [root@zabbixapp01 zabbix]# yum install -y php-bcmath.x86_64
Loaded plugins: replace, ulninfo
No package php-bcmath.x86_64 available.
Error: Nothing to do
[root@zabbixapp01 zabbix]# yum install -y php-bcmath.x86_64
Loaded plugins: replace, ulninfo
No package php-bcmath.x86_64 available.
Error: Nothing to do
[root@zabbixapp01 zabbix]# yum install -y php-mbstring.x86_64
Loaded plugins: replace, ulninfo
No package php-mbstring.x86_64 available.
Error: Nothing to do

Comment: in current repo absent this lib

Comment: Can you send a list of your repositories? "yum repolist"

Comment: Both packets can be installed using the base repository

Comment: I wrote repo list in text question